# Can you avoid Gson converting "<" and ">" into unicode escape sequences?

Tags: java, json, gson

I noticed that [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) converts the string "<" into an unicode escape sequence in JSON output. Can you avoid this somehow, or do characters like "<" and ">" always have to be escaped in JSON?

Consider this example which prints `{"s":"\u003c"}`; I'd want simply  `{"s":"<"}`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(new Foo()));  
}

static class Foo {
    String s = "<";
}
```

Context: the piece of JSON I'm creating has nothing to do with HTML pages or even JavaScript; it's just used to pass certain structured information to another piece of software (embedded in a device, written in C).

Comment: Does GSON default to doing that? Whoa. That is rather strange default setting, although perfectly legal thing to do from JSON spec perspective.

Comment: Yeah, it was surprising to me too. Luckily the [remedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147012/can-you-avoid-gson-converting-and-into-unicode-escape-sequences/4147245#4147245) is easy once you know where to look. :) Otherwise, after one day's experience with it, I find Gson a really clean, nice library, with a great [user guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) too!

Comment: This also happens to the "=" character, which turns into "\u003d".

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You need to [disable HTML escaping](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping--).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: I wonder why it's on by default. JSON has nothing to do with HTML. The [spec](http://www.json.org/) states only `"` and `\\` need to be escaped.

Comment: Guys, thats not worked for me. i am using ''com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'' &&  ''com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0''. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

the Ampasand symbol was replacing with \u0026 , by using this it got resolved.

Comment: But sometimes, for the sake of readability and compatibility with external input data, such as deserialization of objects, the control from the [data source] here may be impossible or too expensive; this time , Reasonable use of Gson's own principle mechanism and configuration may be a better choice.