# Gson's .toJson method replaces < with \u003c

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert a Java object having values in one variable as a string of xml .

```
Eg: <soapenvelope... >
```

After using

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(testVO)
```

It replaces "<" with \u003c. I want to avoid this as I will then display the data in jquery datatables which fails to recognize the string of xml and print some random values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147012/can-you-avoid-gson-converting-and-into-unicode-escape-sequences

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping%28%29

[Can you avoid Gson converting "<" and ">" into unicode escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147012/can-you-avoid-gson-converting-and-into-unicode-escape-sequences)