# realm is generating � while retrieving data which is encoded in utf-8

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, gson, realm

I am using realm to store and retrieve utf-8 for nepali(Devnagari) characters but when retrieving � is also generating which is not a nepali(Devnagari) character and not stored. How to solve this issue? Along with realm I have used Gson and retrofit.

```
Gson gson =  new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
final RealmResults<Information> realmObj = realm.where(Information.class).findAll();
if (realmObj != null) {
    List<Information> obj = realm.copyFromRealm(realmObj); 
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);                     
}
```

which generates

```
२५ द���खि ४० वर्षः
```

Comment: Did you look into this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147245/3145960

Comment: yes i tried it and didnt work

Comment: � is a marker to tell users that programmers have mishandled their text and lost some of it. Unfortunately, I can only suggest finding some other way of checking that the text is stored properly so you can tell if the mishandling is before or during storage, or after or during retrieval.