# Octa encoding of Google gson library

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to build json string from my java object. This object contains string with '&' and '='. 
Now after calling gson.toJson my string changes from those charecters to \u003d and \u0026.

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setUrl("www.koko.com?k=1&v=2");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    System.out.println(g.toJson(myObj));

}

public static class MyObj{
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"url":"www.koko.com?k\u003d1\u0026v\u003d2"}
```

Expecting:

```
{"url":"www.koko.com?k=1&v=2"}
```

Any suggestions how to avoid this behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147245/7557573

> You need to disable HTML escaping.
>
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();