# Gson not able to serialize map with equal sign correctly

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java Hashmap as follows:

```
map.put("targetStatus","2");
map.put("targetAvailable","Availability=false")
```

I am using Gson library to convert the map into Json :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(map);
```

Output

```
{
"map": {
 "targetStatus": "2",
  "targetAvailable": "Availability\u003dfalse"
  }
}
```

Could someone help me out, why is the *=* sign not displayed when converted to json.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fluffy Thanks !That worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you avoid Gson converting "<" and ">" into unicode escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147012/can-you-avoid-gson-converting-and-into-unicode-escape-sequences)